# Custom Tiles, Ajax call in GetTileURL not working properly

Tags: deepzoom, openseadragon

I am using the customtile to make the list of the images based on the ajax call, I can not see the console.log handled after making ajax call...

```
getTileUrl: function (level, x, y)
                {
                    console.log("URL::->" + "http://s3.amazonaws.com/com.modestmaps.bluemarble/" + Math.max(0, level - 8) + "-r" + y + "-c" + x + ".jpg")
                    var data = { level: Math.max(0, level - 8), x: y, y: x };

                    apiGet(root + 'DeepZoom/image', data, function (json) {
                        console.log("count:->" + count++);
                            //based on json data show the green line for the shortest path for the start pole and end pole

                            console.log("Length:->" + json.length);
                            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                                console.log("URL:->"+json[i]);
                                return json[i];
                            }
                        });

                    //return "http://s3.amazonaws.com/com.modestmaps.bluemarble/" +
                    //        Math.max(0, level - 8) + "-r" + y + "-c" + x + ".jpg";
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is discussed in https://github.com/openseadragon/openseadragon/issues/549; it's not possible.